# Laravel - Saving new related member doesn't update parent

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I've got these two models (changed the names for this example because they aren't in english):

`Task`:

```
public function times() {
    return $this->hasMany('TaskTime', 'id');
}
```

`TaskTime`:

```
public function task() {
    return $this->belongsTo('Task', 'task_id');
}
```

Also, inside the model `Task`, I've got this method:

```
public function start() {
    $now = Carbon\Carbon::now();
    $time = new TaskTime;
    $time->task()->associate($this);
    $time->beginning = $now->toDateTimeString();
    $time->save();

    // testing
    echo $this->times()->get()->toJson();
    echo '<br/><br/>';
    echo $this->toJson();
    die();
}
```

When I call the `start()` method, it correctly saves a new row in the `TaskTime`'s corresponding table, with the foreign key correctly set to the `Task`.

The line `echo $this->tempos()->get()->toJson();` correctly prints the rows, including the new one.

The line `echo $this->toJson();` doesn't print the new row! Only prints the old ones.

I've tried `save()` and `push()` in both `$this` and `$time` and it still doesn't print the updated data!

Any idea of what can be causing this? I've been trying to debug this thing since yesterday and I ran out of ideas...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is, that `Eloquent` does not update relation on the already loaded models after `attaching`, `saving`, `associating` etc.

It creates the relation, ie. inserts/updates necessary tables (`attach`, `save`, `saveMany`) or sets the relation on the model without saving anything in db (`associate`).

So in your case `$this` has no idea that newly created `$tempo` has been associated to it.

Now,

```
`$this->tempos()->get()->toJson();`
```

runs a new query to fetch related `tempos`, this is why you get correct result, but

```
`$this->tempos;
```

must have been loaded before associating new one, so they won't be reloaded from the db, thus you get 'old' result.

---

What you need is this:

```
public function start() {

    // do what you need with $time
    $tempo->task()->associate($this);
    $tempo->save();

    $this->load('tempos'); // reloads relation from db

    // or:
    $this->tempos->add($tempo); // manually add newly created model to the collection
}
```

Mind thought, that latter solution will cause unexpected result if `$this->tempos` have not been already loaded.

Comment: Wow! I seriously thought that $time->save(); would automatically perform $this->tempos->add($tempo); to maintain consistency!